# Fisher Z transformation vs T-Test in cross sectional correlations

Tags: correlation, t-test, fisher-transform

I want to compare the correlations of stock related measures. According to the paper referenced below, time series can be compared for statistically different correlations with the Fisher Z transformation (confidence intervals), RMSEs with a paired T-Test and cross sectional correlations with a regression framework.
Now, the regression framework does not apply to my research and I wonder whether I can use the same methodology of the time series correlations (Fisher Z) to the cross sectional correlations. 
Is there an econometric reason why it would not be appropriate?

Best

Goyenko, R.Y., Holden, C.W. and Trzcinka, C.A., 2009. Do liquidity measures measure liquidity?. Journal of financial Economics, 92(2), pp.153-181.